# I found obfuscated code in a comment on my code c# 4

Tags: c#-4.0, obfuscation

i have developed C# class library, and didn't use any dotfuscator applications, but when i open the DLL by code reflection i find "// Obfuscated Code" comment in all functions instead of the function code
i don't know how that happened, please advise

Comment: What application do you use to open the DLL by code reflection?

Comment: You may not use an obfuscator, but do you use anything else that performs post-processing after your build? E.g. code contracts, postsharp, etc.

Comment: to open the DLL I use this program "DevExtras - CodeReflect"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever no i dont

Comment: Utilities like this are worth what you paid for it.